# sql server count() function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this Sql Query to show me how many task under Project but the problem it doesn't display Projects with 0 task can someone help me?

```
SELECT Projects.projectName AS [Project Name],
    COUNT(Projects_tasks.taskID) AS #tasks,
    Projects.projectID AS [Project ID]

FROM Projects

INNER JOIN Projects_tasks
ON Projects.projectID = Projects_tasks.projectID 

GROUP BY Projects.projectName,
    Projects_tasks.taskID,
    Projects.projectID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Left Join`

```
SELECT     Projects.projectName AS [Project Name],
                  ISNULL(COUNT(Projects_tasks.taskID),0) AS #tasks, Projects.projectID AS [Project ID]

FROM       Projects LEFT JOIN
                  Projects_tasks ON Projects.projectID = Projects_tasks.projectID 

GROUP BY Projects.projectName,Projects.projectID
```

also remove the `column` that you are counting in the `group by`

Answer (score 1):

Use LEFT join, ISNULL(), and do not group by the column you are counting.

```
SELECT     Projects.projectName AS [Project Name],
                  ISNULL(COUNT(Projects_tasks.taskID), 0) AS #tasks, Projects.projectID AS [Project ID]

FROM       Projects LEFT JOIN
                  Projects_tasks ON Projects.projectID = Projects_tasks.projectID 

GROUP BY Projects.projectName,Projects.projectID
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a LEFT JOIN to make sure the projects with 0 tasks are also included

```
SELECT     Projects.projectName AS [Project Name],
           ISNULL(COUNT(Projects_tasks.taskID),0) AS #tasks, Projects.projectID AS [Project ID]
FROM       Projects LEFT JOIN
                  Projects_tasks ON Projects.projectID = Projects_tasks.projectID 

GROUP BY Projects.projectName,Projects_tasks.taskID,Projects.projectID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN

You're not seeing 0, because there is no task to join to.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN`. And also `COALESCE` to convert `null` values. `COALESCE` must be inside the `COUNT` function since the column `Projects_tasks.taskID` can be **NULL**.

```
SELECT Projects.projectName AS [Project Name],
       COUNT(COALESCE(Projects_tasks.taskID, 0)) AS #tasks,
       Projects.projectID AS [Project ID]
FROM   Projects
         LEFT JOIN Projects_tasks
            ON Projects.projectID = Projects_tasks.projectID 
GROUP BY Projects.projectName,
    Projects_tasks.taskID,
    Projects.projectID
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your query will ever return more then 1 task as number of tasks. The Projects_tasks.taskID should not be in the group clause.
And for your problem, you have to put LEFT JOIN instead of inner join and it will work.

```
SELECT Projects.projectName AS [Project Name],
    sum(case when Projects_tasks.taskID is null then 0 else 1 end) AS #tasks,
    Projects.projectID AS [Project ID]

FROM Projects  

LEFT JOIN Projects_tasks
ON Projects.projectID = Projects_tasks.projectID 

GROUP BY Projects.projectName,
    Projects.projectID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing INNER JOIN into LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT     Projects.projectName AS [Project Name],
       ISNULL(COUNT(Projects_tasks.taskID),0) AS #tasks, Projects.projectID AS [Project ID]

FROM Projects LEFT JOIN Projects_tasks ON Projects.projectID = Projects_tasks.projectID

GROUP BY Projects.projectName,Projects_tasks.taskID,Projects.projectID
```